# Restore all hidden Windows for all applications?

Tags: mission-control, application-switcher

I have a pretty good idea what direction this question is gonna go, but I'll ask it anyway.

Is there any way or workaround to quickly un-hide all hidden applications? By which I mean, applications that have been tucked away with CMD+H and are normally restored with CMD+Tab when you want to access them.

Comment: Hidden windows are unwanted citizens of Mac, even the Mission Control does not show them!

Comment: That's the hidden motive of my question. If you could unhide everything before firing up mission control, it would suddenly be useful :)

Comment: Not really an answer, but [DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/english/about.html) can do it by hot-key, so it is possible.

Comment: @Tetsujin , nice, this looks very promising. Hopefully I can find a way to do it without something as full-featured as dragthing

Comment: tbh, I've been using DragThing since 1995 (really;) & find it indispensable - but, of course, for a one-trick pony, I wouldn't insist it was your 'fix'

Comment: It looks like Keyboard Maestro offers this option as well. This is slightly more sensible than using Dragthing, but ideally I'd want the secret sauce applescript that accomplishes this